# Add-Migration in package management console of visual studio not creating database in my local sql server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, entity-framework-migrations

I am new .net core with angular and also **EntityFrameworkCore**. I am using a video tutorial on **.Net Angular Core** using [this link](https://www.freetutorialsus.com/building-applications-with-angular-11-and-asp-net-core-5/). In the module 6, Services and Back-End - chapter 7, Creating the Database with EF Core, a database MoviesAPI is created by configuring in appsettings.json and startup.cs. I followed teacher's steps in the video to create a database MoviesAPI in my local SQL Server Express[image: My Local SQL Server 2012].

First I tried using the teacher's configuration for DefaultConnection in appsettings.json but after using that my command Add-Migration Initial in my package manager console in Visual Studio didn't create any database MoviesAPI in my sql server.

```
    "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MoviesAPI;Integrated Security=True;"

  }
```

Then I tried using this below but it didn't still create a database in my sql server on my computer.

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=LAPTOP-5QTMTD1A\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MoviesAPI;Integrated;Security=True"
```

In both cases, I got a build succeeded in my package manager console.

> Build started...
> Build succeeded.
> To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.

My Startup.cs

```
            using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
        using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
        using MoviesApi.Filters;

        using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

        namespace MoviesApi
        {
            public class Startup
            {
                public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
                {
                    Configuration = configuration;
                }

                public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

                // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
                public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
                {
                    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options=> {
                        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                    });
                    services.AddCors(options => {
                        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => {
                            var frontendURL = Configuration.GetValue<string>("frontend_url");
                            builder.WithOrigins(frontendURL).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
                        });
                    });
                    services.AddControllers(options=> {
                        options.Filters.Add(typeof(MoviesExceptionFilter));
                    });
                    //E nsures all actions and controllers have simple caching mechanism in the webapi
                    services.AddResponseCaching();
                    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer();
       
                    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                    {
                        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MoviesApi", Version = "v1" });
                    });
                }

                // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
                public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,ILogger<Startup> logger)
                {

      
                    if (env.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                        app.UseSwagger();
                        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MoviesApi v1"));
                    }

                    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

                    app.UseRouting();
                    app.UseCors();
                    //Intercept http request returned from the cache
                    //app.UseResponseCaching();
                    app.UseAuthentication();
                    app.UseAuthorization();

                    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                    {
                        endpoints.MapControllers();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

After reading some comments on similar post on **stackoverflow**, I ran the the command in my package manager console and it ended up giving me these warnings but I don't know if these warnings have anything to do with not being able to create a databse through Add-Migration Initial command.

> Update-Database -Verbose

Warnings

> Security Warning: The negotiated TLS 1.0 is an insecure protocol and is supported for backward compatibility only. The recommended protocol version is TLS 1.2 and later.
> Security Warning: The negotiated TLS 1.0 is an insecure protocol and is supported for backward compatibility only. The recommended protocol version is TLS 1.2 and later.
> Security Warning: The negotiated TLS 1.0 is an insecure protocol and is supported for backward compatibility only. The recommended protocol version is TLS 1.2 and later.

Comment: From your error message, you need to enable tls 1.2 in your project. Refer to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/kestrel-default-supported-tls-protocol-versions-changed#recommended-action).

Comment: @Rena yes, i solved this issue using these steps in this links https://learn.mediasite.com/course/enabling-tls-1-2/lessons/sql-server-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

I have a project with this problem of TLS 1.0 too. It works normally on my school PCs, but in mine it doesn't (the browser doesn't accept the protocol). About ur problem with the creation of the database, have u tried using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18? My project uses it, and my string connection it's like this:`"ConnectionStrings": { "DBcadastro_clientes": "Server=PCNAMEHERE\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DBcadastro_clientes;User Id=sa;Password=sa;"}, "AllowedHosts": "*" }`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31180556)